# getting error 504 in api : Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/auth/status

Tags: reactjs

i am working on react, when i run the app, and when api calls, it gives me this error in my local server : `Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/auth/status`, i have installed 
`http-proxy-middleware` still getting this error, in setupProxy.js, i have set all things, still getting error, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/auth', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/*.svg', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
}
```

Comment: I think your server is giving an error. In the browser dev tools (network tab) you can right click on the request and copy as fetch. Check the script and try to make the request directly. You can run the copied script in browser console from http://localhost:5000/ so you won't get cors errors.

Comment: getting this reponse from console :Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/auth/status", redirected: false, status: 504, ok: false, statusText: "Gateway Timeout", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }

Comment: I put the comment there to confirm this is a server error so you should run it after opening page localhost:5000 if it errors then there is no use submitting a Rect question since your server has the error. Or the error comes from your front end by sending invalid request but you should have seen that from the code you copied.

Comment: thanks i resolved the issue, it was issue in my code